# ios, maintain single viewcontroller as android does?

Tags: android, ios

It seems you can keep only one instance of an activity using the following code in android.

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

How can you achieve the same effect in ios?

Answer (score 0):

There's no standard way of doing that, but you can make your view controller a singleton this way:

```
+ (instancetype *)sharedViewController {
    static FooViewController *sharedViewController = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedViewController = [[FooViewController alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedViewController; 
}
```

You'd then be able to get the shared instance using:

```
FooViewController *fooViewController = [FooViewController sharedViewController];
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. That certainly is one piece of information. How should I `reuse` the singleton viewcontroller? If I push the singleton viewcontroller, would it be automatically be removed from a navigation stack?

Comment: I'm not aware of what exactly the Android code does, so I think I might have understood your question wrong. Does it create a new instance of the Activity and deallocate the old one? Or just keep a single instance that is usable everywhere?

Comment: It keeps a single instance. I don't know exactly how android does its thing though :(